# Have Image Files Printed on Screen Inside While Loop (Corresponding to the Thread ID)?

Tags: php, mysql

**This Question Has Gotten Updated:**

I have these columns stored in the table "thread":

```
id - title - caption - image_file_id - hashtag_id - date_created
```

An example for "image_file_id", it are the ID numbers of the "images" table for the image files:

```
583, 584, 585
```

The script should get the *"title"* and the *"caption"* from the "thread" table and print them with a while loop, ***then*** it also should get the *image files* from the "images" table and also print them ***corresponding*** to the thread ID.

E.g.

```
Thread ID: 35
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Caption</p>
1. <img src=""/>
2. <img src=""/>
3. <img src=""/>
4. <img src=""/>

Thread ID: 36
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Caption</p>
1. <img src=""/>
2. <img src=""/>
```

**EDIT:**

After the suggestion by "Steve" I have gotten it to work with this script here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

    include("connect.php");

?>
<?php

    $tqs = "SELECT * FROM `thread`";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    // $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr);


    // The ID numbers of the image files.


    // This prints e.g.:
    // Array ( [0] => 583 [1] => 584 [2] => 585 )
    // print_r($exploded);

    // echo "<br/><br/>";

    //This prints e.g.:
    // 3
    // print_r(count($exploded));


    // Select the image files by the ID numbers

    // Iterate through he image files:




while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr)){

    echo "<div class='content'>";
    echo "<div class='title_caption'>";
    echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['caption'] . "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='parent-container'>";

    // Have the image files printed on screen here!

    $exploded = explode(", ", $row['image_file_id']);

    foreach($exploded as $id){
        $tqs_two = "SELECT `image_file` FROM `images` WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "'";
        $tqr_two = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs_two) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        $row_two = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr_two);
        echo "<img src='http://localhost/gallerysite/multiple_image_upload/thumbs/" . $row_two['image_file'] . "' />";
    }

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to ask if this script is correct, as said it is working.

This script goes row by row, though my question would be: how can I ***ensure*** that the image files are correctly printed on screen ***corresponding*** to the "thread ID"?

Comment: simply iterate over `$exploded` with a foreach loop, withing the while loop.

Comment: Can you please show an example how to add `$exploded` into the MySQL query? I am getting an `Array to string conversation` error. Sorry for this question, though I am getting confused with this at the moment.

Comment: Please update your question to show your current (broken) code, and i'll try and help

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have gotten it to work. I have updated the question. Also I am wondering how to ensure that the image files are printed on screen correspond to the thread id. As of yet it goes row by row. I would appreciate if you would check it. Again, I have been at first confused with this. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by using `IN` query, to reduce you overall number of queries:

```
$tqs = "SELECT * FROM `thread`";
$tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr)){

    echo "<div class='content'>";
    echo "<div class='title_caption'>";
    echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['caption'] . "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='parent-container'>";

    // No need to explode, just use IN query
    $tqs_two = "SELECT `image_file` FROM `images` WHERE `id` IN ({$row['image_file_id']})";
    $tqr_two = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs_two) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    while($row_two = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr_two)){
        echo "<img src='http://localhost/gallerysite/multiple_image_upload/thumbs/" . $row_two['image_file'] . "' />";
    }

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Ideally you would have the image ids stored in a normalized fashion - eg using a lookup table, but then you could do the whole thing with one query.